# how to display sql rows from which i can click on one for a new sql statement based on that row

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Sorry for the vague question, im not sure exactly what to ask as im not sure how exactly to do what i want to do. so here it is.

I have two db tables. banned and reports. one is a list of people who have been banned, the other table consists of reports put in by security officers.

When someone shows up onto the property we run their visitor code and enter their license plate number. we then see 4 text box forms with some information. 1. visitor code 2. resident name 3. license plate number (we enter) 4. visitor name.

The two key fields here are the visitor name and the plate number. I can look up in each data table by either of these 2 pieces of information.

now from here if we try to put their visit in the system, if the plate or the name show up in the banned data table, a grid view shows that row with the pertinent information.

here is where im not sure where to go from. The text fields are still populated at this point. once i know that either the name or the plate has been put on the ban list, I need some control that will populate with all of the rows from the reports table that the name or plate are found in, and then click on that row which would then populate a couple text boxes with information from that row of the reports table.

i am not sure which control, if any, or what method can be used to accomplish this

thanks for the help

Comment: Are you using MVC, WebForms, or WebApi+JS Framework?

Comment: Show some code. real Homework

Comment: WebForms. And there really is no code right now. ATM all it does is populate a gridview with rows that match the name or plate number. The next step is what i'm not sure how to do. populate rows where i can click on a row and that click will initiate code that will populate soem froms with other data from that field. I actually know how to write that code, i just don't know what control to use that will let me run code and handle the data it is displaying.